# Get last/latest value for a metric for all tags in opentsdb

Tags: api, hadoop, hbase, opentsdb

The scenario is something like:

i have a metric value.open or value.close that have records for different symbols (Tags) like A, B, C .....such 3000+ Symbols.

> 1. I want to get the latest value.open for all the symbols (tags) through api/query if possible or any other way if possible.

### (localhost:4242/api/query/last?timeseries=stk.Open{symbol=*} doesnt work)

### (localhost:4242/api/query/last?timeseries=stk.Open{symbol=AAPL} returns empty json)

localhost:4242/api/query?start=2016/01/01-00:00:00&m=sum:stk.Close{symbol=*}
gives datapoints for all the symbols for the metric.

> 2. Is it possible to get rid of Aggregators in the query.

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no latest query in openTSDB. You have to specify the relative time or absolute time
2. is it possible to get rid of agg?
   No, openTSDB will always agg data on the same datapoints. You may try uids query if you want to avoid agg. Or try kariosDB

Answer (score 0):

> 1. I want to get the latest value.open for all the symbols (tags) through api/query if possible or any other way if possible.

**No** - it's not possible to query the `last` for a metric for all the values of `tag`. The

> `<tagk>=*`    Wildcard filter, effectively makes sure the tag key is
>   present in the series

- is not available/works for last/ endpoint (which works fine with [`query`](http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/api_http/query/index.html) endpoint).

If in your case there's only one tag i.e. symbol (with different values - AAPL, GOOG, FB, etc) you can just use the last endpoint only just specifying the metric name:

```
localhost:4242/api/query/last?timeseries=stk.Open
```

---

> 2. Is it possible to get rid of Aggregators in the query.

**No** - `start` and `m` are the 2 required parameters for the query endpoint, and the bare min is `m=<aggr>:<metric-name>` :